# UIPickerView Spin Effect

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm looking to implement a UIPickerView where the user presses spin and the picker selects a random option. I'm curious if there are any ways to make the spinning effect last longer?

The only way I've really thought of, or seen, is increasing the number of items in the component simulating that the picker is really "spinning". Is this my only option?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may test the actual performance with the huge number UIPickerView first, or actually build a slot machine component like this one:

[iPadSlotMachine](https://github.com/timburks/iPadSlotMachine)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With the stock iOS controller, no, I do not believe this is really possible.

Your idea might work, but will probably suffer from some graphical glitches as you add/remove elements during animation.  Definitely worth trying though, to see if it is good enough for your needs.

Unfortunately, I think you'd have to write your own custom controller to really get the "slot machine" effect you're after properly.  I would suggest google around and checking github, etc to see if anyone has written an open source one.